# Drop doesn't work with Dynamic lists

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic

So I have this code right here.

```
DynamicModule[{points = {}}, 
     EventHandler[Dynamic[points], {"LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (
         AppendTo[
          points, {RandomInteger[{-25, 25}], RandomInteger[{-25, 25}]}]
         ),
       "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (
         Drop[points]
         )}]]
```

The goal is to add an element to the "points" list whenever LeftArrow is pressed, and remove its last element whenever RightArrow is pressed. Everything is fine with adding elements, but nothing happens when I try to drop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues.

1. Syntax for [`Drop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html) is incorrect.
2. You are not assigning the result of `Drop` to `points`.

Replace `"RightArrowKeyDown"` action with

```
points = Drop[points,-1]
```

[`AppendTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html) appends to the symbol passed.  `Drop` merely returns the result of the drop; the  symbol is unaffected.  Therefore you must assign back to the symbol.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add -1 when I pasted the code here. Thanks a bunch!